# Image Not Being Uploaded To Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, storage

Below is the code given for the dart file in which I was trying to uploading an image to Firebase storage :

```
class _UploadImageState extends State<UploadImage> {
  File? _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Firebase_STORE.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase_STORE.FirebaseStorage.instance;

  var imageurl;

              roundbtn(
      Title: 'UPLOAD',
      onTap: () async {
        Firebase_STORE.Reference ref = Firebase_STORE.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/Images' + '1223');
        Firebase_STORE.UploadTask uploadtask = ref.putFile(_image!.absolute);

        await Future.value(uploadtask);
        imageurl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

FireBase Storage Rules :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

I have Tired to upload the image again and again, but still it would not be uploaded.

Comment: You might be signed in so the Firebase security rules you have in place are making you trouble. Do you get any error messages or anything?

Comment: Thanks Guys. 
Problem has been resolved. There was an error in the rules
New Rules :
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
      
    }
  }
}